# Melhorar performance de função que determina se é palíndromo

Tags: c#, .net, string, desempenho

Objetivo: otimizar a performance

Descrição do problema:

Tenho uma função que me retorna se a palavra é um palíndromo com `true` senão com `false, até ai tranquilo, porém preciso melhorar a performance da função.

#### Código:

```
static bool checkPalindrome(string inputString) 
{
    
    if(inputString.Length>=1 && inputString.Length <= Math.Pow(10, 5))
     {
        string palindromo = "";

        for (Int32 i = inputString.Length-1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
                  palindromo += inputString[i];   
        }
         if (palindromo.ToLower().Equals(inputString.ToLower()))
             return true;
         else
             return false;
        
     }
     else
     {
        return false;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Além deste código não ser idiomático C# (parece que foi escrito em outra linguagem), ele faz muitas coisas sem necessidade, inclusive alocação de memória.

A principal mudança é não alocar um novo objeto que é algo que pode criar um problema de mudança, só fiz comparações porque o problema só pede isso. E comparar um por um é a melhor forma. Apesar de não ser visível esses métodos que está usando são compostos por laços, eles varrem os dados inteiros todas as vezes, é muito ruim.

Outra mudança é sair tão logo saiba que não é palíndromo, e isso deve ocorrer muito, é fácil não ser. Quando você já sabe que não é não tem porque continuar o algoritmo.

Por último verifico apenas até a metade, porque se eu continuar o resultado já é sabido. O que diferiria eu analisar o primeiro com o último e depois o último com o primeiro? Dá no mesmo.

Não melhorei a validação porque não sei os requisitos.

```
using static System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine(checkPalindrome("ana"));
        WriteLine(checkPalindrome("abba"));
        WriteLine(checkPalindrome("oki"));
    }
    static bool checkPalindrome(string inputString) {
        if(inputString.Length >= 1 && inputString.Length <= 100_000) {
            for (var i = 0; i < inputString.Length / 2; i++) if (char.ToLower(inputString[i]) != char.ToLower(inputString[inputString.Length - i - 1])) return false;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ySUYG5). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d9mrx2). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/Palindrome.cs).

Comment: Maniero depois de ver o seu código vi o quanto o meu faz coisas sem necessidade rs..
Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Minha sugestão é essa, primeiro converte a `String` em um `Array`. Depois inverte o `Array`. Volta numa `String` para então fazer a comparação em maiúsculas.

```
public bool éPalindromo(string entrada)
{            
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(entrada) && new string(entrada.ToCharArray()
    .Reverse().ToArray()).ToUpper() == entrada.ToUpper();
}
```

Comment: Isto piorará a performance imensamente.

Comment: @Maniero me explica uma coisa(não é uma pergunta, só um esclarecimento). O Runtime do c# não vai criar um binder para cada método invocado? Esses binders, não serão armazenados um único callsite para `ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray()`. Então depois da terceira chama os únicos métodos que terão impacto não serão `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, CallSiteBinder.Bind() e entrada.ToUpper()?

Comment: Não, nada disso existe. Na verdade o que está afirmando também não faz sentido do ponto de vista lógico. E o problema maior é a alocação de memória de vários objetos e que são percorridos várias vezes. O único método que não tem impacto é o que você disse que terá. São 6 *loops* (todos alocam). O dele tinha 3, o meu tem 1 sem alocação.

Comment: Faz o teste de performance e veja o quarto resultado.